# How to get Count as 0 when no data is found in table?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, rdbms, select-query

Consider I have a below table name "temp"

```
   id   | name
   -----+-------
      1 | AAA        
      2 | BBB        
      3 | BBB
```

Am getting the count of the names with below query

```
  SELECT name , count(*) FROm temp where name IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC') group by 1
```

When I execute the query I got the below output

```
      name | count 
------------+-------
AAA        |     1
BBB        |     2
```

But I need the below output

```
    name | count 
    ------+-------
   AAA   |     1
   BBB    |     2
   CCC   |     0
```

How to get this output???

Comment: This is really a display issue. Consider handling such issues in a presentation layer (if that's available)

Comment: I am glad you got it. Check my answer as accepted, please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another temporary table `tmp2` with values 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'... and then your selection query would be something like this:

```
SELECT tmp2.name, count(temp.name) 
FROM tmp2 
LEFT JOIN temp ON temp.name=tmp2.name
GROUP BY tmp2.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. With your answer I have made some changes and got the output.

Comment: Please beware that MySQL is a multi-user environment. Whatever you insert into `tmp2` will be shared by all users, unless you properly define it as temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure SQL single-query cross-DBMS solution you need something on this line (untested code):

```
SELECT names.name, count(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT 'AAA' AS name
    UNION ALL SELECT 'BBB'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'CCC'
) names
LEFT JOIN temp ON names.name=temp.name
GROUP BY names.name
```

This involves dynamic SQL so you need to either:

- Write a complex procedure to generate it.
- Use your client language (Java, PHP, whatever...). In this case you could simply take the easy path: keep your current query and take care of empty values in your display code.

If you don't mind having several queries, another alternative would be a temporary table to replace the `names` ad-hoc subquery. This feature is normally not cross-DBMS but [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtableas.html) seem to share the basic syntax:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE names (...)
```

If you even need to support a DBMS where temporary tables behave too differently, you could always emulate them with a regular table and an extra *session_id* column to isolate data from different users.

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join between the actual values you want in your output (although this could be a `SELECT DISTINCT` from another table where all the values reside if available), this can be generated using `SELECT` and `UNION` and your query. I often us this for BI where the 'presentation layer' is less well defined in some cases.

See an example below:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (id INTEGER, `name` CHAR(3));

#ALTER TABLE temp CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1, 'AAA'), (2, 'BBB'), (3, 'BBB');

SELECT A.`name`, IFNULL(B.nameCOUNT, 0) nameCOUNT FROM
    (
    SELECT 'AAA' `name` UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'BBB' `name` UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CCC' `name`
    ) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) nameCOUNT FROM temp GROUP BY `name`
    ) B
ON A.`name` = B.`name`;
```

Note the commented collation statement, not sure if this will be necessary on your setup, uncomment if you see an error like this:

```
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Let me know if you have any questions, regards,

James

Comment: I'd just avoid using Latin-1 and UTF-8 in the same application.

Comment: Definitely, didn't have the luxury of choosing this in the server I used to test